# Need to wrap the text in a column

Tags: tables

some texts inside a column should be wrapped to the next line, however as I see from the following code, the text length is too large that interfere with the rightmost columns.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
The table \ref{label1} 

  \begin{table} 
  \centering    
  \caption{my table}
  \label{label1}
  \begin{tabular}{ |l|p{4cm}|p{1cm}| }
    \hline
    A & B & C \\ 
    \hline
     \multirow{3}{*}{Gromacs}   &  \texttt{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}    &    62\%   \\
                               &  \texttt{bbbbbb}     &    15 \%   \\ 
                               &  \texttt{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}   &   10\%   \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output is shown below

[image]

Comment: It *should* wrap to the next line, except LaTeX doesn't know where to hyphenate, due to the choice of  a long unknownn ‘word’.

Comment: So, how can I fix that? Or even using smaller font size for that column?!

Comment: With normal sentences, it will wrap. Maybe you can load the `ragged2e` and `array` packages and replace   `p{4cm}` with `>{\RaggedRight}p{4cm}`.. Also setting `\tabcolsep` to a lower value (default is 6pt) and making the last column as `c` can help. Last suggestion: use `tabularx`, this way: `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{l>{\RaggedRight}Xc} ... \end{tabularx}`.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{ |l|>{\RaggedRight}p{4cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2cm}| }` has no effect

Comment: What is the real sentence?

Comment: I replaced `\begin{tabular}{ |l|p{4cm}|p{1cm}| }` with `\begin{tabular}{ |l|>{\RaggedRight}p{4cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2cm}| }`. I also wrote `\usepackage{ragged2e}` at the top of the file.

Comment: Could you post a *complete* example code, starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: I have updated the post with my original code. Even if you use `\begin{tabular}{ |l|>{\RaggedRight}p{4cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2cm}| }`, you will see the same output.

Comment: Do you really have single words with that many letters?

Comment: They are actually some long names with 'underline'. For example, `non_bonded_Elec_uiF_post`. I just wanted to show the output.

Comment: For introducing hyphenation in non-standard words, you can add `\-` in the middle of the word at the hyphenation point.  If it needs to break there, the hyphen will be added...if not, the hyphen won't show.  Also, as others have noted, ragged right justification helps the appearance in narrow columns.

Comment: Yes. `\-` wraps the word. However, I want to know is there any way to PUT but NOT show the '-'? Because `non_bonded_Ele\-c_uiF_post` will put '-' and may cause misunderstanding about the name. I mean, maybe the reader believe that '-' is actually part of the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution, with `tabularx` and `xurl`. I added a variant, which automates word wrapping in the whole column, in case all cells in the second column (except the column head) should be typed in this way, with the `collcell` package.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{xurl, collcell}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\collectcell\url}X <{\endcollectcell}}

\usepackage{multirow}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\UrlFont{\tt}}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

The table \ref{label1}
  \begin{table}[!h]
\centering%
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
  \caption{my table}
  \label{label1}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ |l|U|l| }
    \hline
    A & \multicolumn{1}{l}{B }& C \\
    \hline
     \multirow{3}{*}{Gromacs} & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & 62\% \\
                               & non_bonded_Elec_uiF_pos_non_bonded_Elec_uiF_pos & 15 \% \\
                               & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & 10\% \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}

\noindent Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
  \begin{table}[!h]
\centering%
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
  \caption{my table}
  \label{label1a}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ |l|X|l| }
    \hline
    A & B & C \\
    \hline
     \multirow{3}{*}{Gromacs} & \url{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}& 62\% \\
                               & \url{non_bonded_Elec_uiF_pos_non_bonded_Elec_uiF_pos} & 15 \% \\
                               & \url{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc} & 10\% \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
noindent Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I found that `\url` will do the whole job! You can try `\usepackage{xurl}` and `\AtBeginDocument{\def\UrlFont{\tt}}` and `\begin{tabular}{ |l|p{4cm}|p{2cm}| }` and `\url{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}`.

Comment: `xurl` loads `url`, but can split ‘urls’ at more points.

Comment: Yeah... That is interesting. Because instead of courier, I can use url and it will better handle the hyphenation.